# Moving projects away from GitHub - backing-up / exporting repos

Tags: github

Is it possible with GitHub to download a file / folder with all of the commits, notes, issue tracking etc?

So that you can move from GitHub to Bitbucket, or if you no longer need GitHub (and thus no longer need to continue paying to host your private repository) but you still want all of the commits, notes, issue tracking etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is quite possible but not necessarily in a way that will allow importing in to another product such as BitBucket.

Where can you find this tool? On GitHub, ofcourse!

It is called [github-backup](https://github.com/joeyh/github-backup) and the specifics of what gets back up and what doesn't [are described here](https://github.com/joeyh/github-backup/blob/master/README.md).

Particularly of note though is that private repos aren't accessible through this tool (at this time, anyway)!

Comment: Thanks, its a shame thought about the private repos, thats what i was looking to use it for, as i dont use my Github account any more, but still pay for it, just to host the private repos.. which is a bit of a pain